# ¿Qué significa 'Víveme'?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado, letras-de-canciones

Me refiero a la letra de la canción de Laura Pausini, [***Víveme***](https://youtu.be/jKlYf1oArQg):

> Víveme sin miedo ahora, que sea una vida o una hora

Entiendo perfectamente la palabra **Vivir**, pero me confundo con la frase *víveme*. ¿Qué significa?

Answer (score 9):

En el contexto de la canción sería como que la disfrute con intensidad, que esté junto a ella, que la ame.

Comment: ?Sera un uso comun de la palabra vivir?  Hasta donde yo sepa, no lo es.

Comment: Por lo menos en Cuba se usa mucho la frace vivir como para decir que tenga una experiencia en algo...ejemplo...`Hay que vivir el comunismo para saber lo que es`, o `Vive la vida sin temores`

Comment: No me parece poco común. En la respuesta de @sendai dejé un comentario más relacionado con ella que me parece más apropiada.

Comment: @EmilioGort no querrás decir `frase`?

Comment: @VladimirNul yes..good catch...se me fue la C ahi..jejeje

Answer (score 4):

Yo entiendo **vivir** en esa frase con el sentido de **experimentar**.  Te pongo por ejemplo de este uso una frase que encontré en el diccionario de Wordreference: "Yo vivo la música de una forma distinta." Es decir, experimento o siento la música de otra forma que los demás.

Esta es la [acepción del DRAE](https://dle.rae.es/?id=byZS22V%7CbycwmXJ):

> 11. tr. Sentir o experimentar la impresión producida por algún hecho o acaecimiento. *Hemos vivido momentos de inquietud. Todas sus alegrías y sus penas las vivimos nosotros.*

Aclaro que el español no es mi lengua materna.

Comment: Yo voto por esta respuesta! Efectivamente, vivir también implica experimentar. De hecho podrías citar esta acepción de la RAE para complementar tu respuesta: `11. tr. Sentir o experimentar la impresión producida por algún hecho o acaecimiento. Hemos vivido momentos de inquietud. Todas sus alegrías y sus penas las vivimos nosotros.`

Comment: Y el link a la definición anterior: https://dle.rae.es/?id=byZS22V|bycwmXJ

Answer (score 3):

Antes y después de escuchar la canción aquí esta mi interpretación.

**Antes** vivir a través de una persona.

**Después** vivir y disfrutar de diferentes experiencias (agradables) con una persona.

Es interesante ver como la primera definición es más literal, mientras que la segunda parece ser más figurada.

Answer (score 1):

Podría significar que otro individuo aproveche el tiempo, momento, oportunidad que está pasando con el individuo al que está refiriéndose en ese momento, ya que tal vez no se pueda repetir o no dure mucho. (Ej: María, víveme ahora que estoy aquí).

Answer (score 1):

A mi me parece... vivir a través alguien.  En este contexto, Pausini quiere que se le viva.
"Live through me" sería en inglés.

The word vicarious comes to mind.

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo interpreté como arriesgarse a amar a alguien, decidirse a amarlo y "vivirlo", vivir el amor y la historia que pueden construir juntos sin importar el tiempo, ni los juicios de otros, ni las apariencias.